# How to install python 2.6 on lenny

Tags: installation, python, debian-lenny

I would like the easiest way possible to install 2.6 on Lenny. I get really frustrated with compiling from source cause i can never get it right.

any help will be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to view this forum : 
http://www.comanswer.com/question/how-do-i-install-python-2-6-on-debian-5-0-lenny-using-apt-get

Comment: From the comment on that post: "This is a good way to break your system...."

Comment: this works... but it also now gives me errors when trying to run my program.